# using php to check if xml is atom or rss

Tags: php, dom, rss, feed, atom-feed

i'm writing a php code which has to determine if given xml is in "atom" or "rss" format. After observing atom and rss xml files, i decided classify xml based on a root element. If root element is `"<feed"` it's an atom xml. If it's `"<rss"` it's not an atom.

How can i perform that check using DOM? So far i have:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($resp);
$feed = $dom->getElementsByTagName("feed");
if($feed != NULL)
echo 'it\'s a atom!';
```

but it's not working quite right....There's no errors, it just write "it's a atom" even if it isn't

Comment: please use code-formattig next time (i corrected that for you as it looks like you're new here). also: please try to use some more code - what is `$dom` in yoour code?

Comment: While I can't be sure `$dom` is likely a DOMDocument.  That is the only object I know of which has a loadXML method.

Comment: Sorry, i made suggested improvements. Hope it's looking better now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll wager that you can get that a hint easier.  If you're looking for a root element name examine:

```
$dom->documentElement->tagName;
```

***That isn't tested***, but it should give you what you are looking for in a much cleaner and clearer way.

Comment: Now it's tested and it works! Thanks! I'll choose this instead of "lonesomeday"'s solution because of simplicity.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if $resp is a string or a filepath, but here is what I might do.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filepath);
$root_element_name = $xml->getName();
if ($root_element_name  == 'feed') {
    // is atom feed

} else if ($root_element_name  == 'rss') {
    // is rss feed

}
```

This will load the XML, and find the name of the root node. If the root node is named feed, it is atom, if the root node is rss, it is rss.

Comment: +1 because this will work, but I expect the OP is using DOMDocument elsewhere in the code, given that they're working with Atom/RSS feeds...

Comment: I would guess, based on the signature of <a href="http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php">loadXML</a> that this is a String of the actual XML.

Answer (score 2):

looks like `$dom` is a `DOMDocument` -  in that case, what i would try to do is the following:

```
$dom->loadXML($resp);
if($dom->getElementsByTagName("feed")->length > 0 && $dom->getElementsByTagName("rss")->length <= 0){
  // atom feed
}else{
  // rss feed
}
```

(i never used DOMDocument, just read the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/de/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) - i'm sorry if this is wrong)

**EDIT:**

just saw your additional code - wahts wron with it is checking for `null`. getElementsByTagName will always return a [DOMNodeList](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domnodelist.php) (an empty one if no elements where found)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than testing for `null`, check the number of items returned:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($resp);
$feed = $dom->getElementsByTagName("feed");
if($feed->length != 0) {
    echo 'it\'s a atom!';
}
```

Comment: You may want to test feed to see if it's null regardless.  Perhaps it is instinct learned from Java, but I can't stand those "Attempted to access property of non-object" warnings.

Comment: @cwallenpoole `getElementsByTagName` *always* returns a `DOMNodeList`. [See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php).

Comment: You know, I thought that I had issue with that returning null.  Now that I'm thinking about it, maybe it is that the length was 0 and I tried to address an index which didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how/where from you are parsing data you can check the headers for `application/atom+xml`. Alternatively, you may want to check using `strpos('http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom')`.